# Custom module .install does not create table in database

Tags: 7, database, installation

I want to create database table for my custom module.

Inside `mymodule.install` I have:

```
function mymodule_schema(){
    $schema['a_visits'] = array(

    'description' => 'visits table',
    'fields' => array(
        'id' => array(
            'description' => 'make id primary key auto increment',
            'type' => 'serial',
            'not null' => TRUE,
        ),
        'oferta' => array(
            'description' => 'nazwa oferty',
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'length' => '255',
            'not null' => TRUE,
        )
    ),
    'primary key' => array('id'),
    );
    return $schema;
}

function mymodule_install() {
   drupal_install_schema('a_visits');
}


function mymodule_uninstall() {
   drupal_uninstall_schema('a_visits');
}
```

Then I've moved the module's file to server under `sites/all/modules/custom/mymodule` and enabled it via admin panel. Unfortunately **no table in database has been created** (the module is listed as active now).

Comment: You don't have to explicitly install the schema anymore: https://api.drupal.org/comment/3073#comment-3073 . However, i ran your code and the table was created in my database. Can you disable, uninstall and then enable the module? Also, any notices/warnings in the dblog?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hook_schema` alone is sufficient to create database tables. I assume you are just disabling and then enabling the module which will not help you to create tables in the database.
To get it working, `admin/modules' locate your module and disable it. Then navigate to 'admin/modules/uninstall' and again locate your module and uninstall it. 
After this, go to`admin/modules', and enable your module.
Now you can find the respective tables in your database.

You can also use drush for the same.
`drush dis module_name`, then
`drush pm-uninstall module_name` and finally
`drush en module_name`.

Also, as per @OPTASY Canada, do check your dblog for any warning or error.

Comment: `drush dre module_name` also disables, uninstalls and renables it with one command.

Answer (score 2):

Only this much will work. make sure you first uninstall and reinstall this module again.

```
function mymodule_schema(){
    $schema['a_visits'] = array(

    'description' => 'visits table',
    'fields' => array(
        'id' => array(
            'description' => 'make id primary key auto increment',
            'type' => 'serial',
            'not null' => TRUE,
        ),
        'oferta' => array(
            'description' => 'nazwa oferty',
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'length' => '255',
            'not null' => TRUE,
        )
    ),
    'primary key' => array('id'),
    );
    return $schema;
}
```